# Protect app memory from being read by another app

Tags: security, memory

I want my app memory to be protected from being read by another app on both Windows and Linux.
Is there any reliable method to make the OS fully restrict the app memory (whole memory which can grow) from being read by another process?

Comment: The reliable method is to let the OS handle it.

Comment: @ceejayoz, Unfortunately OSes explicitly allow cross-process shenanigans (eg [ReadProcessMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory) API on windows)

Comment: Exactly! And if your app handles passwords or any sensitive data you better make it secure just in case. There are always some vectors of attack so it's good to limit them in every possible way. Full disk encryption helps (against eg. OS mem dump to hard drive!), but IMO being able to protect app RAM memory should be default or at least easy nowadays. I've checked it is possible to read memory on Win10 by process PID as well as using popular Cheat Engine. Not good, should be encrypted/password restricted.